# Merge results of WITH RECURSIVE queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.3

I have the table called `users_edges` for storing company employees structure.

It has the following columns:

```
id           integer Auto increment [nextval('users_edges_id_seq')]  
from_user_id integer NULL    
to_user_id   integer     
link         integer
```

Indexes:

```
UNIQUE  from_user_id, to_user_id, link
PRIMARY id
```

Foreign keys:

```
from_user_id users(id) CASCADE CASCADE
to_user_id   users(id) CASCADE CASCADE
```

Executive director is the top of graph, so `from_user_id` is `NULL` for that record.

Other records describes relationships between employees.

There is also link column that needed for separating different link types.

Currently there are only two types but its number will increase in the future.

First link type is `by departments` and the second one is `custom` (by undocumented positions plus regional location).

Currently I need to get all parents and children of the given employee.

The link is optional and if it's not passed, we need to merge all results.

I use `PHP` with `PDO` for building query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE temp AS (
    SELECT t1.from_user_id FROM users_edges t1
    WHERE t1.to_user_id = :from_user_id
    AND link = :link -- This is optional

    UNION

    SELECT t2.from_user_id FROM users_edges t2
    INNER JOIN temp ON temp.from_user_id = t2.to_user_id
    WHERE link = :link -- This is optional
)

SELECT * FROM temp
WHERE from_user_id IS NOT NULL
```

If I execute two queries separately (`link = 1` and `link = 2` for the same user) and merge results excluding duplicates I get the correct results.

*Results:*

This query with `link = 1`:

```
User 1
User 2
```

With `link = 2`:

```
User 1
User 3
```

So correct result after merging and excluding duplicates will be:

```
User 1
User 2
User 3
```

If I select with one query (for example `where link IN (1, 2)`) I get expected employees, but with extra people:

```
User 1
User 2
User 3
User 4
User 5
User 6
```

But obviously is not flexible solution.

The question is: how to do it with one query?

Maybe we need pass additional argument in `temp` or use conditional expressions?

I don't include children query because it's similar and if I realize how to do it for parents, I can get the children in similar way.

Comment: `where link = :link`, I use this for getting records with one link type only.

Comment: If you want to get it for two link types, then why not use `where link in (1,2)`? You need to then include that into the join condition in the recursive part `ON temp.from_user_id = t2.to_user_id and temp.link = t2.link`

Comment: Yes, it will be used too. Another link types will appear in the future, and there are some situations where I need to filter records with two or more different link types together. But there are also situations where I need all link types, so link filter is omitted (meaning all link types should included). Anyways, `where link in (1,2)` gives extra records that are not presented when execute each query separately.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Do you _want_ to filter on the link type or don't you? Can you post some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: Yes, sometimes filter is needed. The problem is selecting parents / children with two or more link types. For one it works as expected.

Comment: Then you need to include the link type in the join as I have shown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71150/discussion-between-arogachev-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Comment: Added this in join part, also added `link` to select part of table `t2`, but got this error: `ERROR: column temp.link does not exist`. How to correctly define this for `temp`? Passing as parameter?

Comment: Tnanks! I added parameters, solved ambiguous columns problem, added distinct to exclude duplicates. Now it's working as expected. You can issue this as an answer.